# Errors in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am follow https://codingwithjoe.com/flutter-navigation-how-to-prevent-navigation/ for show AlertDialog but have two error:

1. When tap away from dialog box (dismiss barrier without tap any button) get runtime error:

```
  Dart Error: Unhandled exception:Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
```

2. child: new AlertDialog( ‘child is deprecated and shouldn’t be used’.

Code:

```
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Do you want to exit this application?'),
          content: new Text('We hate to see you leave...'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: new Text('No'),
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: new Text('Yes'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
#0      ModalRoute.willPop (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NavigatorState.maybePop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1783:57)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Navigator.maybePop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1133:34)
#3      BackButton.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/back_button.dart:91:19)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
#5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/g<…>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "boolean expression must not be null" is not enough information. The stack trace shows where this exception was caused.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added

Comment: `child` is deprecated - it's recommended to use `builder` instead. But doesn't matter - I've tried your code - everything works fine. Maybe problem not in `_exitApp` method?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovskyThanks for reply! Try tap away from dialog box (anywhere not on dialogbox). This give dart error

Answer (score 2):

Make your method `async` and use the `await` keyword :

```
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog(  ...
```

If you don't want to dismiss your Dialog when you tap outside of the container, set `barrierDismissible` to false.

```
showDialog(barrierDismissible: false, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! What is reason?

Comment: if you check the code of showDialog,  it returns a Future, so you have to mark your method async and use await to wait until you receive a response from your Dialog. if you don't wait, you will return null.